# Split a list into table and relate it

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have one table named User with different columns. One of them is a list and I need to get it out to another table for each User. The information comes from a .csv file and i have used:

```
DELIMITER ',' QUOTE '"' CSV HEADER;
```

When copying it as it was like `"{English, Armenian, Chinese}"`
I have a lot of users.

```
-----------------User-----------------  

name                       Albert  
date                        2020  
languages        {English, Armenian, Chinese}
```

---

I have tried using

```
regexp_split_to_table(user.languages, '}') FROM User
```

But I only get a table with a single column with all the languages from all the users with some '{' in between.

My goal is to create another table or tables with the languages and a reference to the languages every User speaks.

Comment: What SQL engine are you using? PostgreSQL and many other DBMSs have array functions to flatten arrays into rows:
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/functions-array.html Check out <code>unnest</code>. Edit: Realized you are reading in this column as a string. Some libraries (Pandas, etc.) might be able to parse this directly into a list (and then further flatten that list). Definitely would love to hear what technologies you are using to help you out some more.

Comment: PostgreSQL, but theoretically it must be portable between DBMSs

Comment: I'm with the basics of SQL such as `INSERTS` or `SELECT`

Answer (score 0):

With Postgres, you can render the string as an array and then unnest the array into its elements.  Here is an example against your data:

```
select
  name, date,
  unnest (regexp_split_to_array (replace (replace (languages, '{', ''), '}', ''), ', *'))
from users
```

This probably looks like a hot mess, so some assumptions:

- I assumed your list might or might not have the brackets, so it replaces them if they are there and doesn't if not
- Assuming the language field will not contain a `{` or a `}`
- Stripping optional padded spaces between languages

When I ran this I got the following output:

```
Albert  2020    English
Albert  2020    Armenian
Albert  2020    Chinese
```

Because of the greatness of PostgreSQL arrays, this will not be portable to other DBMSs...  at least not any that I have used.